# How do I store one completion handler in a class so that all methods could use it?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, nsurlsession

Supposing I have a class with class methods only and within a method I have two NSURLSessionDataTask / NSURLSessionUploadTask instances which have a completion handler like this:

```
^(NSData *responseData, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
//here parsing the response etc.    
}
```

which are 100% identical for both tasks.

What's the best way for me to create one completion handler in a class to use for both of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a Class method that returns this completion handler, this way both other methods can call this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I was thinking of, I was not sure.